# Wrong preview image shown in documentation mini-tour

Tags: bug, documentation-discussion

To see this go to [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), then follow along as shown in these pictures below. If you have already dismissed it, [logout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout) out of stackoverflow, then go to the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) link.

Click on "Earn Reputation" button

[image: earn-rep-button]

[image: wrong-preview]

Look at the highlights and you'll see it. This preview image for "Example upvoted" surely dates back to the time when each upvote gave +10 reps to the editor. I think it is time this preview is updated!

PS: I don't like to call it a bug, but I didn't find any other suitable tag to use either. Feel free to edit the tag.